# Should Q&A questions be subject to the same rules about duplicate questions if the answer given is unique?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, self-answer, instant-self-answer

Put a lot of work into an in-depth tutorial of Java Filters, only to have it marked as a duplicate of a question about servlets and filters in which someone did a quick skimming post about Java filters. I feel like this was marked without the user realizing it was a "share your knowledge" post, and the question portion of a Q&A post can need to be vague to facilitate a broad, descriptive answer. With these posts, it's the ANSWER portion that contains all the meat. Should they be subject to the same stringent QUESTION duplicate rules as normal posts?

Comment: there are lots of good answers posted which are often linked to but are themselves marked as dupes.  so that in itself is not a problem.  The problem is that being DVed it is in danger of being deleted.  Why didnt you post that as an answer to the other one?

Comment: Also, SO is not for tutorials.  If you are planning a self-answer, and discover that "the answer contains all the meat", something is wrong.  Questions must be real questions, not placeholders for self-answers.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, all of the rules about posting a question apply equally to all questions.  The fact that you've posted your answer changes nothing.  Likewise, the fact that you're posting an answer to your own question doesn't change how the answer should be evaluated either; both should be evaluated exactly the same as if they weren't posted by the same user.

If there is some information that you want to provide and there is an existing question on the topic, you can simply post your answer to the canonical question.  You should not be creating a duplicate question just to post your own answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that while it *can* mean the old one will be closed as duplicate of your new one, for any chance of that to happen instead of the other way around your question and answer must be clearly superior. Still, better upgrade the old question.